# message from ROSbridge server to client

Tags: tcp, server, client, ros

Is it possible to send messages from the ROSbridge server to a connected client? I've connected an Android application using tcp, and able to send JSON messages from the app to the server. But is it possible to send messages in the other direction as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as [in the tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/RunningRosbridge) you create a websocket by starting rosbridge. You would have to consume that socket. Not sure if rosjava can consume that for your android app